# How to set up onelogin SAML in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, saml, onelogin

I am integrating the onelogin SAML API for Ruby tool kit to my current project. I configured the SAML settings. Here is my controller:

```
class SamlController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, :only => [:consume]  

  def index
    #settings = Account.get_saml_settings
    settings = :get_saml_settings
    request = Onelogin::Saml::Authrequest.new
    redirect_to(request.create(settings))
  end

  def consume
    response = Onelogin::Saml::Response.new(params[:SAMLResponse])
    response.settings = Account.get_saml_settings

    logger.info "NAMEID: #{response.name_id}"

    if response.is_valid?
      session[:userid] = response.name_id
      redirect_to :action => :complete
    else
      redirect_to :action => :fail
    end
  end
```

For `def index` method have settings and request object but when it redirect the  page ie redirect_to(request.create(settings)), I am getting error:

> no method "create" for nil class.

I think it calling the create method but not return any values. can you please anyone check it and let me know your concerns/suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

According to https://github.com/onelogin/ruby-saml the declarations should be:

```
OneLogin::RubySaml::Authrequest
and
OneLogin::RubySaml::Response
```

It seems that the docs for the toolkit on their website are outdated. Use docs provided in the gem.

From the gem docs:

```
Version 0.8.x changes the namespace of the gem from OneLogin::Saml
to OneLogin::RubySaml. Please update your implementations of the gem accordingly.
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you reviewed this github repository that contains a working example of ruby-saml and rails4?
https://github.com/onelogin/ruby-saml-example

Also important is the ruby-saml version that you are using since some methods are not available on older versions.